# Removing \n and \r with Regexp from csv file with node

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm trying to read the contents of a .csv file that has city information, as such :

```
Paris,2138551,5.272,1,138,900,48.864716,2.349014
Marseille,794811,1.959,423,439,43.29695,5.38107
Lyon,472317,1.164,251,730,45.74846,4.84671
Toulouse,433055,2.135,230,826,43.60426,1.44367
Nice,338620,1.669,180,545,43.675819,7.289429
Nantes,277269,1.367,147,879,47.21725,-1.55336
```

So I want to parse the file, and transform it into an array (not an object) with .split(',').

Here's my problem, when I'm using Regexp to remove these damn \n and \r with the following regex, it doesn't work, they are still bugging my output :

```
var cities = data.replace(/\n/g, '').replace("'", '').split(',');
```

Then, when I use this regex, it removes all the "," as well ! So I tried replacing them with "_", which works, but then I have another problem, it also removes the minus sign (-) from the latitude and longitude :

```
var cities = await data.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g,
'_').replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').split('_');
```

(btw the "_" doesnt appear in the code above on split idk why)

**How can i Remove the \n and \s like the second regex does BUT without touching the "," and "-" ?**

I'm really not into Regex.

EDIT: I've used one of the solutions bellow, but the output is still bugged, meaning that blank lines are still not removed by the following line :
var cities = await data.replace(/(?:\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, ',').replace(/[^\w\s,-]/gi, ',').split(',');

There must still be /n or /r despite the regex above. Anyone knows how to get rid of the lines ?

the output is bugged as u can see :

> console.log('City: '+i+' sur '+cities.length+' - "'+cities[i]+'", "'+countryName+'", '+cities[ii]+', '+cities[iii]+',
>   '+cities[iv]+', '+cities[v]+', '+cities[vi]+'\n');

City: 0 sur 1095 - " New York City", "United States", 8537673, 31, 709, 34, 245

City: 6 sur 1095 - "881", "United States", 40, 730610, -73, 935242 ,  Los Angeles

City: 12 sur 1095 - "3971883", "United States", 14, 752, 15, 931, 949

City: 18 sur 1095 - "34", "United States", 052235, -118, 243683 ,  Chicago, 2720546

Comment: By splitting on `,` you will get a single dim array. Is that what you want ? Show an example of what your expected output should be.

Comment: You should replace the newlines before the split. Replace `/(?:\r?\n)+/g` with `,`. Then split on `,`.

Comment: What is that `await` doing there? Why are you using `/i` on a random regex? What is `.replace("'", '')` supposed to do?

Comment: `/[^\w\s]/gi` matches and removes `,` and `-`. Replace with `/[^\w\s,-]/gi`

Comment: I want an output like this : [Paris, 2222, 2222, 2.22, ..., Marseille, 3333, 444, 3.22, ] etc.

Comment: The await is from the async function that hosts this

Comment: Wiktor, I will try your solution

Comment: Unfortunately, Wiktor, your solution still doesnt replace the problem with backlashes, I still have random spaces (\n \r and dont know what else)

Comment: Basically, I need a solution that removes ALL \n and \r and empty lines that are on the CSV after each entry, without touching alphanumerical characters "," and "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code from  Wiktor Stribiżew

> /[^\w\s,-]/gi –

And added a "." in it, as that was causing arrays to be separated

Moreover, I found that the person that has sent me the CSV changed its structure... so now I think it works, here's the final result. Thanks for the help

> var cities = await data.replace(/(?:\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, ',').replace(/[^\w\s,-.]/gi, ',').split(',');